# dirname() X amount of times on path of file PHP

Tags: php, directory

I need to do a `dirname()` on a file path multiple times to exclude sub-folders, so like this:

```
dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

The amount of times I need to do this on a file path is completely dynamic (not fixed) so I need to somehow do it variable `$x` amount of times...

I could do this:

```
$x=6;//amount of sub-folders involved in the path

if($x==1){dirname(__FILE__);}

elseif($x==2){dirname(dirname(__FILE__));}

elseif($x==3){dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));}

elseif($x==4){dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));}//and so on.....
```

But thats not exactly a professional way of going about it, and it will never be reliable (if `$x`=9999999....).

Does anyone know how I'd go about doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the `dirname` function `$x` times, that's called a loop:

```
$x=6; //amount of sub-folders involved in the path
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
while(max(0, --$x)) {
    $dir = dirname($dir);
}
```

Comment: Sure, you don't need recursion, but recursion just looks awesome! :D

Comment: For things that repeat -> iteration I'd say ;)

Comment: Which way would be better for performance - Recursion or this way?? Thanks

Comment: Naturally this way ;) Actually the difference can be neglected, recursion is harder to follow than a loop, so keep your code clean, don't look for performance. But most often the more simple the code is, the better it performs.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the answer my friend!

```
function go_up_x_times($path, $x) {
    if ($x <= 0) {
        return $path;   // we're done, yay!
    }
    return dirname(go_up_x_times($path, $x - 1));
}
go_up_x_times(__FILE__, 5);
```

Comment: Recursion? That makes my pony cry.

Comment: Because you don't need recursion here. This function exists for the sole purpose to create a loop which is available in PHP out of the box.